# Ubuntu unattended upgrades conflict with startup script on google cloud compute engine

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-18.04, apt

Using a GCP Ubuntu 18.04 image, plain.

I use startup scripts on vm to automate the deployment of features and changes to the base image. I have one that start with the following :

```
#! /bin/bash
add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/'
apt update
apt -y upgrade
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt -y install libpam-dev libpam-ldap r-base
```

Unfortunatly on some machine that haven't ran in a while, I get the following error:
From /var/log/syslog :

```
startup-script: INFO startup-script: dpkg: error: dpkg frontend is locked by another process
```

From my investigation I can see that the process `unattended upgrades` is locking the file because it is doing the automatic security updates to the system. If I let the automatic upgrades complete and launch the script manually, everything runs just fine.

Is there a way to delay the execution of the startup script so that it starts after unattended upgrades is done? I mean, something that is more reliable than a simple wait command.

The startup script is configured via the metadata of the vm per GCP documentation.

Thanks a lot and have a great day.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your script wait until the dpkg lock is no longer held.  [This AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/375031/169865) suggests a solution using  `fuser` to see if the lock file is in use by another process:

```
#!/bin/bash

while fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock >& /dev/null; do
  echo "waiting for other package installs to complete..."
  sleep 1
done

add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/'
apt update
apt -y upgrade
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt -y install libpam-dev libpam-ldap r-base
```

Comment: This approach is racy, there could be a conflict in case the background package installs start just after your script checked for it.